# Unit test using CouchBase-Lite mobile without an android application context

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, couchbase-lite

I am trying to create a minimalist test class for testing some of my CouchBase Lite Mobile classes. I have tried mocking the Application context but have been unsuccessful.

The problem is that the CouchBase manager is accessing some of the unimplemented methods on the *MockContext* class.

Here are my approaches so far below:

```
public class ClassToTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testGetAllDocumentsBundle() throws Exception {

        try {
            Manager manager = new Manager(
                 new AndroidContext(new MockContext()), 
                 Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
            assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
```

And:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ItemReaderTest {

    private android.content.Context instrumentationCtx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        instrumentationCtx = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void testGetAllDocumentsBundle() throws Exception {
        Database database = null;
        String databaseName = "test";
        try {
            Context context = new AndroidContext(instrumentationCtx);
            Assert.assertTrue(context != null);

            Manager manager = new Manager(context, Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS); <--- throws exception because context.getFilesDir(); return null in Couchbase Manager.java constructor
            ...
        }
    }
```

Has anyone been able to do this? Do I absolutely *have* to use an actual Activity (i.e. create an actual mobile Application and use it's context to be able to test Couchbase mobile at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully create the manager and database by doing this:

```
class MyMockContext extends MockContext {

    @Override
    public File getFilesDir(){
        File f = new     
          File("/data/user/0/com.example.mypackagename/files");
        return f;
    }
}
```

And initializing the manager with this context:

```
Context context = new AndroidContext(new MyMockContext());
Manager manager = new Manager(context, Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
```

However this does make the test dependent on a specific environment and hard-coded path. Perhaps there is a better solve out there...

Comment: Hello @Willeman, I just wanted to ask if you found a better alternative since then. Also, on a side note, you should accept the answer(even if you wrote it) if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Alator Hi thanks for the tip. Think I might not have had the privileges at the time. Done. Unfortunately have not done any java / android based development since :/